# CSS transition creating problem in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating an animation (it will happen after the creation of the beehive) when the bee reaches the door of the beehive gate it has to become invisible by CSS `display: none;` for this, I am making a logic that when the `transform: translate(0px,0px)`  the newCreatedBee(class of the newly created bee using SVG use tag in js) becomes zero it has to `display: none;` but the problem comes I have given `transition:4s` to the newly created bee (I have consoled bee reached when translate becomes zero) but before the bee reached the beehive gate it is consoling bee reached So, I think this weird behaviour is due to CSS transition property. So how do I console at the exact time when the bee reaches the gate with a smooth transition(but not with this weird problem).
can anyone tell why is happening?

```js
let beehivePiece = document.querySelectorAll(".beehive-piece");
let bees1 = document.querySelectorAll(".corr-p-1");
let bees2 = document.querySelectorAll(".corr-p-2");
let bees3 = document.querySelectorAll(".corr-p-3");
let bees4 = document.querySelectorAll(".corr-p-4");
let bees5 = document.querySelectorAll(".corr-p-5");
let bees6 = document.querySelectorAll(".corr-p-6");
let bees7 = document.querySelectorAll(".corr-p-7");
let beehiveGate = document.querySelector("#beehive-gate");
let gatekeeperBee = document.querySelector(".gate-keeper-bee");
let heroSvg = document.getElementById("hero-svg")


 console.log(heroSvg);
// console.log(gatekeeperBee)


// console.log(beehivePiece[1])

let a = 1500

window.addEventListener("load",check)
function check(){
   setTimeout(()=>{
       beehivePiece[6].style="transform:translate(0px,0px)";
       bees1[0].style="transform:translate(0px,0px)";
       bees1[1].style="transform:translate(0px,0px)";
       setTimeout(()=>{
        bees1[0].style="transform:translate(1000px,250px)";
        bees1[1].style="transform:translate(1000px,250px)";
       },1300)
   },1500)

//  For BEES 2
   setTimeout(()=>{
    beehivePiece[5].style="transform:translate(0px,0px)";
    bees2[0].style="transform:translate(0px,0px)";
    bees2[1].style="transform:translate(0px,0px)";
    setTimeout(()=>{
     bees2[0].style="transform:translate(1000px,250px)";
     bees2[1].style="transform:translate(1000px,250px)";
    },1300)
},2500)

//  For BEES 3
setTimeout(()=>{
    beehivePiece[4].style="transform:translate(0px,0px)";
    bees3[0].style="transform:translate(0px,0px)";
    bees3[1].style="transform:translate(0px,0px)";
    setTimeout(()=>{
     bees3[0].style="transform:translate(1000px,250px)";
     bees3[1].style="transform:translate(1000px,250px)";
    },1300)
},3000)

//  For BEES 4
setTimeout(()=>{
    beehivePiece[3].style="transform:translate(0px,0px)";
    bees4[0].style="transform:translate(0px,0px)";
    bees4[1].style="transform:translate(0px,0px)";
    setTimeout(()=>{
     bees4[0].style="transform:translate(1000px,250px)";
     bees4[1].style="transform:translate(1000px,250px)";
    },1300)
},3500)

//  For BEES 5
setTimeout(()=>{
    beehivePiece[2].style="transform:translate(0px,0px)";
    bees5[0].style="transform:translate(0px,0px)";
    bees5[1].style="transform:translate(0px,0px)";
    setTimeout(()=>{
     bees5[0].style="transform:translate(1000px,250px)";
     bees5[1].style="transform:translate(1000px,250px)";
    },1300)
},4000)


//  For BEES 6
setTimeout(()=>{
    beehivePiece[1].style="transform:translate(0px,0px)";
    bees6[0].style="transform:translate(0px,0px)";
    bees6[1].style="transform:translate(0px,0px)";
    setTimeout(()=>{
     bees6[0].style="transform:translate(1000px,250px)";
     bees6[1].style="transform:translate(1000px,250px)";
    },1300)
},4500)

//  For BEES 7
setTimeout(()=>{
    beehivePiece[0].style="transform:translate(0px,0px)";
    bees7[0].style="transform:translate(0px,0px)";
    bees7[1].style="transform:translate(0px,0px)";
    setTimeout(()=>{
     bees7[0].style="transform:translate(1000px,250px)";
     bees7[1].style="transform:translate(1000px,250px)";
    },1300)
},5000)

 setTimeout(()=>{
     gatekeeperBee.style="transform:translate(0px,0px);"
        beehiveGate.style="transform:translate(0px,0px);"
      setTimeout(() => {
        gatekeeperBee.style="transform:translate(1000px,250px)";
        
    }, 2500);
 },6000)


}


// THIS FUCNTION IS CREATING NEW BEE
function createBees(){
    
    
    setTimeout(()=>{
        let b = heroSvg.innerHTML +=  `<use xlink:href="#theBee" 
        class="newCreatedBee"
        style="transform: translate(1000px,250px);"
         width="400" height="38.4" x="-30" y="290" />
         `
        let newBee = heroSvg.querySelector(".newCreatedBee")
       
       let xAxisOfBee = newBee.getBBox().x
          setTimeout(() => {
            
            if( newBee.style="transform: translate(0px,0px);"){
               
                console.log("bee Reached")
            }


          }, 10000);
    },10000)
    

}
createBees()
```

```css
/* @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap'); */

html,body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
/* html{
     border:5px solid blue;
} */
*,::before,::after{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 box-sizing: border-box;   
}
body{
    font-family:Roboto ;
    /* border: 3px solid red; */
    /* position: fixed; */
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* width:100%; */
}
.container{
    /* border:2px solid black;   */
    /* padding:10px; */
   width:100%;
}
.header{
    /* border:2px solid rgb(255, 179, 0); */
    width:100%;
    padding:.5em .5em;
}
.header-wrapper{
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:space-between;
    padding:.8em 0em;
    /* border:2px solid blue; */
    width:90%;
    margin:auto;
}
.site-title{
  /* border: 2px solid red; */
  margin-left: 2em;
  font-size:2.3em;
  font-weight:400;
    

}
.site-title-span{
    font-weight:750;
    color:#E47700;
}
.nav{
    /* border:2px solid magenta; */
    margin-right:2em;
    /* align-self: flex-end; */
    width:45%;
}
.nav ul{
 display: flex;
 list-style: none;
 font-size:1.5em;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
/* .nav ul li{
  margin-right:1.5em;
} */
.nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
 color:black;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding:6px;
}
.nav ul li a:hover{
    color:white;
    background:#FEBD33;
    border-radius:50px;
    transition: .3s all ease;
}
/* GO AND DO IT IN JS */
.active{
    border-radius:50px;
    background-color: #FEBD33;
    color: white;
    padding:0 12px;
}
.hero{
    /* border:2px solid red; */
    height:40vh;
    /* height:100%;  for mobile view*/
    font-family: poppins;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    
    
}
.hero-wrapper{
    /* border: 2px solid hotpink; */
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:130px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    flex-shrink: 0; 
    align-items:center;


}
.site-info{
        /* position: relative;
        top: 155px;
        left: 10.9em; */
        display: inline-block;
        width: 25em;
        line-height: 28px;
        /* border: 2px solid rebeccapurple; */
}
.site-info-heading{
    font-size:3em;
    /* border: 2px solid rebeccapurple; */

}
.site-info-text{
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 6px;
  /* border: 2px solid rebeccapurple; */

}
.site-info-btn{
    font-size:1.3em;
    border-radius:50px;
    padding:.3em .5em;
    border:none;
    background-color: #33BC00;
    color:white;
    margin-top: 19px;
    /* border: 2px solid rebeccapurple; */

}
.hero-beehive{
     position: relative;
     top: 0px;
     left:0px;
    /* right: 1em;  */
    /* display:inline-block; */
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    /* border: 2px solid rebeccapurple; */


}
svg{
    border:2px solid red;
     width:155%;
     height:25em;
     float:left;
     /* margin-left:0; */
    /* display:inline-block; */
    position:static;
    top:0px;
    left:0;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    
    /* float: right; */

}
#b-peice-1,#b-peice-2,#b-peice-3
#b-peice-4,#b-peice-5,#b-peice-6,
#b-peice-7{
    transform:translateY(px);
    position:absolute;
}
.beehive-piece,.bee{
    transition: .7s ;

}
.gate-keeper-bee,#beehive-gate{
    transition: 2s ;

}
.newCreatedBee{
    transition: 4s linear all ;
}

.forest{
  /* border:2px solid red; */
  width:100%;    
}

/* HONEY BEE WINGS FLYING ANIM */
#small-wing{
    /* anim`ation: small-wing 2s infinite alternate ; */
     animation: check .09s infinite alternate ;
     /* animation-name: check;
     animation-duration: 1s;
     animation-iteration-count: infinite; */
     /* transform: rotate(10deg); */
      
}
#large-wing{
    animation: check .09s infinite alternate ;
    
}
@keyframes check{
    0%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    50%{
        transform: rotate(-.4deg);

    }
    100%{
        transform: rotate(.4deg);

    }
}
.small-wing{
    /* anim`ation: small-wing 2s infinite alternate ; */
     animation: check .09s infinite alternate ;
     /* animation-name: check;
     animation-duration: 1s;
     animation-iteration-count: infinite; */
     /* transform: rotate(10deg); */
    transform-origin: center;
      
}
.large-wing{
    animation: check .09s infinite alternate ;
    transform-origin: center;
    
}
@keyframes check{
    0%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    50%{
        transform: rotate(-2.5deg);
    transform-origin: center;


    }
    100%{
        transform: rotate(2.5deg);

    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="header">
            <!--header open-->
            <div class="header-wrapper">
                <div class="site-title">
                    <p>

                        <span class="site-title-span">B</span>ee
                        <span class="site-title-span">B</span>uzz
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" class="active">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--header closed-->


        <!-- HERO SECTION  -->
        <div class="hero">
            <div class="hero-wrapper">

                <div class="site-info">
                    <h1 class="site-info-heading">
                        <span style="color:#E47700;font-weight:bolder;">B</span>ee
                        <span style="color:#E47700;font-weight:bolder;">B</span>uzz
                        <span style="font-size:.5em;">TM</span>
                    </h1>
                    <p class="site-info-text">
                        We are providing pure
                        forest bee honey and
                        protecting our environment
                    </p>
                    <button class="site-info-btn">
                        Read more
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="hero-beehive">

                    <svg id="hero-svg" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 50 630 630" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">


                        <symbol id="theBee" viewBox="0 0 78 49" >
                            <g id="complete_bee">
                              <path id="bee head" d="M11.553 35.5047C16.3904 38.8245 21.8681 37.8364 24.0023 36.4532V15.1115C22.9352 14.4397 19.5917 13.499 14.7542 15.1115C9.9168 16.724 8.37329 20.5655 7.99604 21.7512C6.88944 25.2291 6.71554 32.1848 11.553 35.5047Z" fill="#FFE818" stroke="black" />
                              <circle id="bee eye" cx="15.532" cy="21.6908" r="2.96412" fill="#313131" />
                              <path id="bee trunk" d="M65.8034 15.1697C45.3154 7.5816 30.1154 12.008 23.9501 15.1697V36.6299C37.3242 43.649 56.6739 38.0527 64.1435 34.3772C78.0156 27.5513 77.7785 19.6049 65.8034 15.1697Z" fill="#FFE818" stroke="black" />
                              <path id="trunk lines" d="M32.961 12.087C30.4711 16.1577 26.9142 26.5519 32.3682 39.3569L35.8065 39.8312C29.8309 27.5004 34.2652 15.5649 36.7551 11.4942L32.961 12.087Z" fill="#4E4E4E" stroke="black" />
                              <path id="trunk lines_2" d="M42.9204 39.8312C36.9447 27.5005 41.2605 15.0907 43.7503 11.02L47.7815 11.1385C45.2917 15.2092 40.5017 27.1448 46.4773 39.4755L42.9204 39.8312Z" fill="#313131" stroke="black" />
                              <path id="trunk lines_3" d="M53.947 38.0527C47.2667 27.313 51.8749 15.6325 54.6584 12.087L58.3339 12.7984C55.5504 16.3439 50.8236 26.246 57.504 36.9856L53.947 38.0527Z" fill="#313131" stroke="black" />
                              <path id="trunk lines_4" d="M63.7528 34.6143C56.6849 26.8661 61.298 16.5925 64.38 14.6955L67.5819 15.8811C65.3292 18.6081 61.4051 23.9435 66.3963 33.1916L63.7528 34.6143Z" fill="#313131" stroke="black" />
                          
                              <path id="small-wing" d="M61.4166 1.06052C55.8203 0.206853 39.1659 8.60919 32.6053 12.0871C54.3264 11.3283 59.9938 9.00435 61.4166 8.05583C63.2303 6.8467 67.0128 1.91419 61.4166 1.06052Z" fill="#99CEFF" stroke="black" />
                          
                              <path id="large-wing" d="M32.9609 11.9685C48.0977 7.26541 80.3166 -2.14073 74.6957 7.34446C68.7675 14.5769 44.3036 13.6679 32.9609 11.9685Z" fill="#81D1FE" stroke="black" />
                              <path id="bee sting" d="M70.4275 30.7017L73.273 27.7376L76 32.7173L70.4275 30.7017Z" fill="#313131" stroke="black" />
                          
                              <path id="antenna" d="M13.1606 15.8811C13.4768 12.6008 12.1173 5.73197 4.14972 4.4989M10.3151 17.8967C9.36656 14.4583 6.09418 8.05584 0.592773 9.95288" stroke="black" />
                              <path id="bee legs" d="M30.3525 39.1198L26.2028 43.151L28.2184 46.2337M35.6879 39.9497L31.7753 44.5738L34.2652 48.605" stroke="black" />
                              <circle id="antenna ball" cx="4.38689" cy="4.38033" r="0.592824" fill="#FFE818" />
                              <circle id="antenna ball_2" cx="0.592824" cy="9.83431" r="0.592824" fill="#FFE818" />
                              <path id="bee behind legs" d="M49.2044 39.2384L45.6475 43.6253L47.6631 45.9965M55.4883 37.8156L50.8643 43.6253L55.4883 46.8265" stroke="black" />
                            </g>
                          </symbol>



                        <g id="beehive 1">
                            <g id="first-beehive-setm">
                            
                                <path id="hive-stem"
                                    d="M353 80C361.284 80 368 86.7157 368 95V97C368 105.284 361.284 112 353 112H15C6.71573 112 0 105.284 0 97V95C0 86.7157 6.71573 80 15 80H217.787C221.765 80 225.58 78.4196 228.393 75.6066L261.393 42.6066C267.251 36.7487 276.749 36.7487 282.607 42.6066L288.971 48.9706C292.853 52.8528 292.853 59.1472 288.971 63.0294C282.708 69.292 287.143 80 296 80H353Z"
                                    fill="#502601" />
                                <path id="leaft-up"
                                    d="M368 0L375.032 7.032C385.896 17.898 392 32.634 392 48C392 63.366 385.896 78.102 375.032 88.968L368 96L360.968 88.968C350.104 78.102 344 63.366 344 48C344 32.634 350.104 17.898 360.968 7.032L368 0Z"
                                    fill="#008100" />
                                <path id="leaf-side"
                                    d="M464 96L456.968 103.032C446.102 113.896 431.366 120 416 120C400.634 120 385.898 113.896 375.032 103.032L368 96L375.032 88.968C385.898 78.104 400.634 72 416 72C431.366 72 446.102 78.104 456.968 88.968L464 96Z"
                                    fill="#33BC00" />
                                <path id="anchor" d="M152 112H184V160H152V112Z" fill="#763A02" />
                            </g>4
                        <g>
                              <!-- beehive piece -->
                            <path id="b-peice-7" class="beehive-piece" style="transform: translate(1000px,250px);"
                                d="M112 432H232C240.837 432 248 439.163 248 448C248 456.837 240.837 464 232 464H112C103.163 464 96 456.837 96 448C96 439.163 103.163 432 112 432Z"
                                fill="#E47700" />
                                <!-- beehive piece -->  
                            <path id="b-peice-6" class="beehive-piece" style="transform: translate(1000px,250px);"
                                d="M72 384H272C285.255 384 296 394.745 296 408C296 421.255 285.255 432 272 432H72C58.745 432 48 421.255 48 408C48 394.745 58.745 384 72 384Z"
                                fill="#FF8800" />
                                <!-- beehive piece -->
                            <path id="b-peice-5" class="beehive-piece" style="transform: translate(1000px,250px);"
                                d="M40 336C143.098 336 200.902 336 304 336C317.255 336 328 346.745 328 360C328 373.255 317.255 384 304 384H40C26.745 384 16 373.255 16 360C16 346.745 26.745 336 40 336Z"
                                fill="#FFA900" />
                                <!-- beehive piece 4 -->
                            <path id="b-peice-4" class="beehive-piece" style="transform: translate(1000px,250px);"
                                d="M24 288H320C333.255 288 344 298.745 344 312C344 325.255 333.255 336 320 336H24C10.745 336 0 325.255 0 312C0 298.745 10.745 288 24 288Z"
                                fill="#FEBD33" />

                                <!-- beehive piece 3 -->
                            <path id="b-peice-3" class="beehive-piece" style="transform: translate(1000px,250px);"
                                d="M40 240H304C317.255 240 328 250.745 328 264C328 277.255 317.255 288 304 288H40C26.745 288 16 277.255 16 264C16 250.745 26.745 240 40 240Z"
                                fill="#FFA900" />

                                <!-- beehive piece 2 -->
                            <path id="b-peice-2" style="transform: translate(1000px,250px);"class="beehive-piece"
                                d="M72 192H272C285.255 192 296 202.745 296 216C296 229.255 285.255 240 272 240H72C58.745 240 48 229.255 48 216C48 202.745 58.745 192 72 192Z"
                                fill="#FF8800" />

                                <!-- beehive piece 1 -->
                            <path id="b-peice-1" class="beehive-piece" style="transform: translate(1000px,250px);"
                                d="M112 160H232C240.837 160 248 167.163 248 176C248 184.837 240.837 192 232 192H112C103.163 192 96 184.837 96 176C96 167.163 103.163 160 112 160Z"
                                fill="#E47700" />


                                <!-- beehive keeper -->
                            <path id="beehive-gate"  style="transform: translate(1000px,250px);"
                                d="M136 384H200V352C200 334.327 185.673 320 168 320C150.327 320 136 334.327 136 352V384Z"
                                fill="#763A02" />
                        </g>



                        <!-- <use xlink:href="#theBee" width="62.4" height="38.4"/> -->
                        <!-- <use xlink:href="#theBee" width="62.4" height="38.4" x="344" y="288" /> -->

                        <!-- corresponding piece-1  -->
                        <use xlink:href="#theBee" style="transform: translate(1000px,250px);" class="corr-p-1 bee" width="62.4" height="38.4" x="80" y="155"  />
                        <use xlink:href="#theBee" style="transform: translate(1000px,250px);"
                        class="corr-p-1 bee"   width="62.4" height="38.4" x="220" y="155" />

                        
                        <!-- corresponding piece-2  -->
                        <use xlink:href="#theBee" style="transform: translate(1000px,250px);"   width="62.4" height="38.4" class="corr-p-2 bee" x="25" y="195" />
                        <use xlink:href="#theBee" style="transform: translate(1000px,250px);" class="corr-p-2 bee"  width="62.4" height="38.4" x="260" y="195" />


                        <!-- corresponding piece-3  -->
                        <use xlink:href="#theBee" style="transform: translate(1000px,250px);" class="corr-p-3 bee" width="62.4" height="38.4" x="-6" y="245" />
                        <use xlink:href="#theBee" style="transform: translate(1000px,250px);" class="corr-p-3 bee" width="62.4" height="38.4" x="290" y="245" />

                        <!-- corresponding piece-4  -->
                        <use xlink:href="#theBee" style="transform: translate(1000px,250px);" class="corr-p-4 bee" width="400" height="38.4" x="145" y="295" />
                        <use xlink:href="#theBee" style="transform: translate(1000px,250px);" class="corr-p-4 bee" width="400" height="38.4" x="-200" y="295" />
                        
                        <!-- corresponding piece-5  -->
                        <use xlink:href="#theBee" style="transform: translate(1000px,250px);" class="corr-p-5 bee" width="400" height="38.4" x="135" y="345" />
                        <use xlink:href="#theBee" style="transform: translate(1000px,250px);" class="corr-p-5 bee" width="400" height="38.4" x="-180" y="345" />

                        <!-- corresponding piece-6  -->
                        <use xlink:href="#theBee" style="transform: translate(1000px,250px);" class="corr-p-6 bee" width="400" height="38.4" x="100" y="390" />
                        <use xlink:href="#theBee" style="transform: translate(1000px,250px);" class="corr-p-6 bee" width="400" height="38.4" x="-150" y="390" />

                        <!-- corresponding piece-7  -->
                        <use xlink:href="#theBee" style="transform: translate(1000px,250px);" class="corr-p-7 bee" width="400" height="38.4" x="50" y="435" />
                        <use xlink:href="#theBee" style="transform: translate(1000px,250px);" class="corr-p-7 bee" width="400" height="38.4" x="-100" y="435" />
                        
                        <!-- gate keeper bee -->
                        <use xlink:href="#theBee" 
                        class="gate-keeper-bee"
                        style="transform: translate(1000px,250px);"
                         width="400" height="38.4" x="-30" y="290" />
                         
                        
                    </svg>

                </div>


               
            


            </div>

        </div>
 
        <div class="forest-container">
            <img src="Group.svg" style="width:100%;"
             class="forest" alt="forest-vector">
        </div>








        <!--END OF THE CONTAINER-->
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event

Comment: @Keith Can you tell by manipulating my code